# Java Drag and Drop in Ubuntu

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, drag-and-drop, jtable

I want to drag a String from a cell of a JTable to e.g. the Browser.

Therefore I wrote something like that:

```
    table.setDragEnabled(true);
    table.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler() {

        @Override
        protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
            isDragged = true;
            return new StringSelection(exportString(c));
        }

        @Override
        public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
            return TransferHandler.COPY_OR_MOVE;
        }

        @Override
        protected void exportDone(JComponent c, Transferable t, int act) {
            isDragged = false;
        }

        protected String exportString(JComponent c) {
            // return some String
        }
    });
```

That works very well under Windows and Mac, but with Linux (Ubuntu) I got some trouble:

The first Drag and Drop works fine, but the second wont even start! The mouse is not changing and no Drag and Drop is done.

If you want an example, you could simply run the jnlp of this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/dropmodedemo.html and try to do two drag and drops.

What can I do to solve this problem? Also, under Linux, the exportDone-Method is never called!

By the way: I tested with Java 6 and 7, both the same behavior!

Comment: Q: Which version of Ubuntu?  Q: Which desktop?  Unity?  Q: You've tried different JRE's: have you tried a different desktop: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-classic-gnome-desktop-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise.html

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 12.10 and 12.04 with gnome-shell and unity.

Comment: I found the "error". I used Opera to test the drag an drop. I draged and droped into a TextField (e.g. the google search field). Now, you cannot drag and drop anymore! But why? And how to solve? And how can I drop text into chrome websites?